# Registering codec in MongoDb using Quarkus

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus

I have the following Enum with a LocalDateTime:

```
public enum OrderStatus {
CREATED,
IN_PROGRESS,
INVALID,
PAID,
CONFIRMED;

private LocalDateTime timestamp;

OrderStatus() {
    this.timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
}

public LocalDateTime getTimestamp() {
    return this.timestamp;
}

public OrderStatus setTimestamp(LocalDateTime timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    return this;
}
}
```

And I've created the following codec but it doesn't get registered automatically:

```
@Singleton
public class OrderStatusCodec implements Codec<OrderStatus> {

@Override
public OrderStatus decode(BsonReader bsonReader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
    System.out.println("Decoding...");

    return OrderStatus.valueOf(bsonReader.readString())
            .setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                    new Date(bsonReader.readDateTime()).toInstant(),
                    ZoneId.of("UTC")));
}

@Override
public void encode(BsonWriter bsonWriter, OrderStatus status, EncoderContext encoderContext) {
    System.out.println("Encoding....");

    bsonWriter.writeDateTime(Date.from(status.getTimestamp().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)).getTime());
    bsonWriter.writeString(status.name());
}

@Override
public Class<OrderStatus> getEncoderClass() {
    return OrderStatus.class;
}
}
```

When I post my Order entity, I don't see the codec getting called. And also when I retrieve Orders, I don't see the timeStamp in the Json format.

And is it also possible to format the timeStamp for the serialization ? Can I use the @JsonbDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss") in my enum on the private field ?

Using:

- Quarkus 1.4.2.Final
- JDK 11
- Maven 3.6.3

Comment: An `enum` with mutable state seems like a very bad idea. If you load more than one document out of Mongo with OrderStatus CREATED, they will all end up with the same date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order MongoDB to use your Codec you must provides both a Codec and a CodecProvider. See this documentation section for more details: https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#simplifying-mongodb-client-usage-using-bson-codec

For you this means something like this:

```
public class OrderStatusCodecProvider implements CodecProvider {
    @Override
    public <T> Codec<T> get(Class<T> clazz, CodecRegistry registry) {
        if (clazz == OrderStatus.class) {
            return (Codec<T>) new OrderStatusCodec();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```